# Calculate trend slope after STL decomposition

Tags: regression, time-series, trend, seasonality

I have a time-series of daily measurements of some quantity for 1995-2011. There's about one measurement every three days.

The data show a strong seasonality (annual cycle).

What I ultimately want is get an estimation for the underlying trend. [STL](http://www.jos.nu/Articles/abstract.asp?article=613) decomposition works fine and gives me seperate trend, seasonality, and noise components of my original time series. But how do I get a quantitative measure for the trend component? A simple linear regression won't do due to the autocorrelation in the noise component. Gavin Simpson suggested using `gls()` from **R**'s *nlme* package, but I'm not sure how I should do that. Which would be the inputs for `gls()`?

Or, are there other suggestions for tackling my problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get a "slope" because STL allows for a nonlinear trend. But you can get the numerical values of the trend as follows:

```
require(fpp)
la10 <- log(a10)
fit <- stl(la10,s.window="periodic")
trend <- fit$time.series[,"trend"]
plot(la10)
lines(trend,col="red")
```

If you really want a linear trend, then don't use `stl()`. Instead, fit a linear trend with seasonal factors:

```
fit2 <- tslm(la10 ~ trend + season)
n <- length(la10)
plot(la10)
lines(ts(fit2$coef[1]+fit2$coef[2]*(1:n)+mean(fit2$coef[-(1:2)]),
  start=start(la10),f=12),col="red")
```

Then `fit2$coef["trend"]` gives the slope of the fitted trend.

I've chosen an example where the trend is relatively linear. In many examples, the trend will be non-linear and the linear model approach will not work.

I've ignored the serial correlation in the residuals, so the estimate of the trend is not efficient, but it is still unbiased.

You can do better using `Arima()` with `xreg` containing the trend and seasonal dummy variables.

Comment: Thanks, what you say makes sense. However, I'm missing something. The trend output from STL is a whole time-series in its own. If I want to describe it, I'll need to fit some model to it. (in my question I chose linear). Now I understand from your answer that I shouldn't fit a model to the trend output from STL. Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: stl is a nonparametric procedure. The trend component is a numerical estimate of the nonlinear trend. If you want a parametric model, don't use stl.